# How can I tell if my page was opened using Window.Open()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an EventDetails.aspx page with details for an event which can be opened by my user using Window.Open() from my Timetable.aspx page. On the EventDetails.aspx page I have a button that allows me to then close the window using the following code:

```
protected void CloseWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.open('','_self');window.close();</script>");
}
```

When I open my window with Window.Open() from the Timetable.aspx page the close window button works fine, however if I navigate independently to the EventDetails.aspx page I am unable to use the close window button - nothing happens!

Is there a way I can determine if the user has navigated using Window.Open() so that I can change the visibility of my button, or better still, is there another way I can close my tab that does not rely on using Window.Open()?

Comment: You could pass a parameter in the query string when you open with `window.open`. If you find it when the EventDetails page loads, you know that it has been opened that way.

Comment: check the value of `window.opener` it will contain a reference to the window that opened your popup

Comment: @ConnorsFan I might try that but I imagine I will have similar issues ie. if the user bookmarks the url after opening the page with Window.Open() and then later tries to return to the url, which will contain the querystring.

Comment: Just in case the query string parameter is still an option for you (dman2306's suggestion is probably better), you could set the parameter to some time value (e.g. now + 10 seconds, in tick number). Checking that value would tell you if it is relevant when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Pass data to opened window so that in opened windows you can make check in js for that data and you can hide or show buttons according to data passed

```
// Store the return of the `open` command in a variable
var newWindow = window.open('example.com','_self');

// Access it using its variable
newWindow.my_special_setting = "Hello World";
```

In Opened Window you can check data like code below

```
window.my_special_setting
```

Added A Jquery Fiddle To Confirm that it will work with '_self'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_self");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes we can add it as second parameter to windows.open updating the code

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes let me confirm it

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I think it should work added a fiddle for that in answer that works with _self

Comment: If I do something like `window.open(location.href, "_self").canClose = true` and execute `window.canClose`, it returns `undefined`

Comment: what is canclose here ?